# Ktor and postgres - batch insert not working

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, pg-jdbc

I have a ktor application, and I'm connecting to postgres DB and using pgJDBC and HikariDataSource, and using exposed ORM. I'm trying to do batch inserts for better performance. However, my inserts keep running as separate insert statements.

As per documentation in exposed
(https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/DSL#batch-insert)

> NOTE: The batchInsert function will still create multiple INSERT statements when interacting with your database. You most likely want to couple this with the rewriteBatchedInserts=true (or rewriteBatchedStatements=true) option of your relevant JDBC driver, which will convert those into a single bulkInsert. You can find the documentation for this option for MySQL here and PostgreSQL here.

I checked the postgres documentation for jdbc
https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/use/

and I added this flag like this

```
private fun createHikariDataSource(
        url: String,
        driver: String,
        user: String,
        password: String,
        maxPoolSize: Int,
        autoCommit: Boolean
    ) = HikariDataSource(HikariConfig().apply {
        addDataSourceProperty("reWriteBatchedInserts", true)
        driverClassName = driver
        jdbcUrl = url
        username = user
        this.password = password
        maximumPoolSize = maxPoolSize
        isAutoCommit = autoCommit
        isReadOnly = false
        transactionIsolation = "TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ"
        addDataSourceProperty("reWriteBatchedInserts", true)
        validate()
    })
```

and tried to pass the flag in the url like

```
val connectionPool = createHikariDataSource(
            url = "$jdbcURL/$defaultDatabase?reWriteBatchedInserts=true",
            driver = driverClassName,
            user = username,
            password = password,
            maxPoolSize.toInt(),
            autoCommit.toBoolean()
        )
```

and still the batch statement won't work

Comment: What method did you use to verify your insert statements are merged?

The exposed documentation mentions `If you want to check if the rewriteBatchedInserts + batchInsert is working correctly, check how to enable JDBC logging for your driver because Exposed will always show the non-rewritten multiple inserts.` Have you checked the link following the documentation (https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/logging/) and enabled logging for jdbc, or did you use another way to verify the wanted behavior?